# How to store textfield into core data with swiftui

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I can't complete a task to store a value with core data when entered into `TextField`, and to be showed again when entering the view. Is it possible?

I need to store `name` and `surname`. For that I created `ProfileData` data model but can't find any relevant info. on how to make it work properly.

Please find below the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ProfileView: View {
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var surname: String = ""
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: ProfileData.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ProfileData.name, ascending: true),
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ProfileData.surname, ascending: true),

        ]
    ) var profile: FetchedResults<ProfileData>
    @EnvironmentObject var profile1: ProfileData

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Meno:")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding()
                        TextField("", text: $name, onCommit: {
                        self.profile1.name = self.name
                        try? self.managedObjectContext.save()})
                    .onAppear {
                        self.name = self.profile.name != nil ? "\(self.profile.name!)" : "Zadajte meno" //here I get error Value of type 'FetchedResults<ProfileData>' has no member 'name'
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        self.profile1.name = self.name
                        try? self.managedObjectContext.save()
                    }
                        }   .padding(.leading, 37)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Priezvisko:")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding()
                        TextField("Zadajte priezvisko", text: $surname)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Profil"))
    }
}
```

Here is my ProfileData+CoreClassData.swift:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(ProfileData)
public class ProfileData: NSManagedObject {

}
```

And here is my ProfileData+CoreDataProperties.swifft

```
//
//  ProfileData+CoreDataProperties.swift
//  UcmMap
//
//  Created by Jakub Adamec on 06/01/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Jakub Adamec. All rights reserved.
//
//

import Foundation
import CoreData


extension ProfileData {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ProfileData> {
        return NSFetchRequest<ProfileData>(entityName: "ProfileData")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var surname: String?

}
```

Comment: You update `profile1` here but where is it saved? Also, you have declared a fetch request but you are not using it, is that intentional?

Comment: I'm not using it right now, because first I wanted to focused on the state that the app is launchd and there is nothing stored in `name` and `surname`. I understand what you mean by saving, but at the time I was posting this question, I couldn't find nothing more to saving textfields with core data with swiftui so this is all I could prepare.

Comment: Updated the code to the most recent version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's full code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

@objc(ProfileData)
public class ProfileData: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    public var id = UUID()
}


extension ProfileData {


    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    public var wrappedName: String{
        get{name ?? "NoName"}
        set{name = newValue}
    }
    @NSManaged public var surname: String?
    public var wrappedSurname: String{
        get{surname ?? "NoSurname"}
        set{surname = newValue}
    }
}

struct ProfileView: View {
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var surname: String = ""
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc: NSManagedObjectContext // it will need you to add new examples of youre entities and save all changes
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: ProfileData.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ProfileData.name, ascending: true),
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ProfileData.surname, ascending: true),

        ]
    ) var profileList: FetchedResults<ProfileData>
    //fetchRequest is a list of all objects off type ProfileData - saved and unsaved

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{

            List{
                ForEach(profileList){profile in
                    NavigationLink(destination: profileUpdateView(profile: profile)){
                        Text("\(profile.wrappedName) \(profile.wrappedSurname) ")
                    }
                }
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    Button("add a new profile"){
                        let newProfile = ProfileData(context: self.moc)
                        newProfile.wrappedName = "Name"
                        newProfile.wrappedSurname = "Surname"
                        }

                }
             }

                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Profile"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("save"){
                if self.moc.hasChanges{
                    do{try self.moc.save()}
                    catch{print("Cant save changes: \(error)")}
                }
            })

        }
    }
}
struct profileUpdateView: View {
    @ObservedObject var profile: ProfileData
    var body: some View{
        VStack {
              HStack {
                  Text("Meno:")
                      .font(.headline)
                      .padding()
                TextField("Zadajte meno", text: $profile.wrappedName)
              }
              HStack {
                  Text("Priezvisko:")
                      .font(.headline)
                      .padding()
                    TextField("Zadajte priezvisko", text: $profile.wrappedSurname)
              }
          }
    }
}
struct ProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let newProfile = ProfileData(context: context)
        newProfile.wrappedName = "Name"
        newProfile.wrappedSurname = "Surname"
        return ProfileView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

notice several things:

1. `FetchRequest` returns you a list of entities of type you define.
   There may be one item, several items or there might be none.
2. If you fetches something, you need to have `ForEach` loop to show the result (most of the time).
3. To do so, I added an `id` to you're entity. Its not connected to CoreData, and every time `FetchRequest` gets new results, id will
   change, but that's fine. The only purpose of it - is to let `ForEach`
   know, which part of loop is connected with exactly object. Therefor
   `ForEach` can change it and show you updates
4. Don't forget to change `codegen` property of your entities in data model to `manual/none`. To do so open DataModel like, select your entity and go to data model inspector (right side of the screen). If you don't the compiler will create those files in compilation itself and this class will be defined twice.
5. If you want to create new object of your type - you need to use MOC. Its the only way to create objects of `NSManagedObject` type.
6. in TextField you can put a BindableObject. You tried to use @State for that purpose, but you don't need it. You can modify ordinary
   objects property just like that: `TextField("Zadajte meno", text: $profile.wrappedName)` The `$` symbol is to make this property
   wrapped `@Binding`. This means, all the changes made inside this
   `View` will translate into this object instantly.
7. You can't just put `@NSManaged` property, because most of them have optional type like String?. I made a computed property
   `wrappedName` to use it simply in Views.
8. I use an `@ObservedObject` wrapper in update View. Its like `@State`, but for classes. you use it when you want instantly update the `View` when this object changes. It also helps create a `Binding`. Your class must meet the `ObservableObject` protocol requirements, but `NSManagedObject` already does, so you don't need to worry about it. All `@NSManaged` attributes are already `@Published`.
9. There is a way to use Canvas even if you using CoreData. Just get the context from `AppDelegate`, create any test entities. But remember, saved changes will add to you're preview.
10. And finally, you need to save all the changes with `moc.save()`. It can throw an exception, so you must do it in `try-catch`. And its
    a good practice to check, if there really are unsaved changes.

Good luck in learning SwiftUI. There is not so much info of using SwiftUI and CoreData. Try to check it on  [hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/introduction-to-using-core-data-with-swiftui), there's much helpful information.

Comment: Hello @Aspid, first thank you for your answer. I've tried to implement your code, but got few errors:  1. when using preview, I can't generate ProfileView `replaced function 'fetchRequest()' is not marked dynamic`  2. I deleted CoreData data model, because there was an error that it's a duplicate of your `@objc(ProfileData` that's correct right?

Comment: 3. I have this view as Tab in Content view, when I simulate the app and click this tab, app crashes `@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {` with error Thread 1: Fatal error: UnsafeRawBufferPointer with negative count. Could this be because of the fact that AppDelegate and SceneDelegate contain methods automatically generated from the time I set the project to use CoreData?

Comment: @redears the last error is looks like you Xcode can't load your DataModel, and therefore can't get access to your entity. Get data model back and check if you load correct model in AppDelegate file

Comment: but when I get it back, it's in conflict with your `@objc (ProfileData)` code, it says it's a duplicate

Comment: to fix 'fetchRequest()' duplicate - I just removed this function. I'm not sure about it, but I believe NSManagedObject has already that function. At least this error appears only in Canvas and doesn't appear in simulator.
If you have duplicate class definition error with 'ProfileData' - you forget to change 'codeGen' property of your entity in DataModel to "manual/none"